# Audio analysis to detect low volume periods

Tags: audio, wav, analysis, volume, detect

i have a sequence of audio files (they are currently both wav and mp3). These files consist of a beep, a pause and then the reply of a person. I need to find the reaction time between the beep and the person replying. There is a lot of data so i would like to make a program that could do this for me. Does anyone have any idea what language this could be done in, or know of any existing programs that will do this. I have looked into the wave tool in python, and can't seem to find any data that represents the low moments.

i program to function like this:

```
wav = open(wave file)
chunk = getNextChunk(wav)
volume = analyse(chunk)
check against threshold
if silent period, check for loud period
find difference
log time in seconds
```

Can anyone help me with this, i know its a very open ended question, but i have no idea where to start with this, i've programmed in java and python among others, but will use whats best, same with the sound format. Would it also be better to make the files mono?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As to your choise of language I would personally choose Matlab. However it costs money, and as you already have experience with python the numpy module might be the right thing for you.

Based on your description of your problem, this could be one approach:

- Load wav
- Find envelope and smooth with a fast time constant
- Threshold
- Find time for beep
- Find time for response
- Calculate difference

Going to mono will be fine and reduce your amount of data at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that works, although my algorithm for detecting audio is pretty lousy, and is not very accurate. The amplitude or frequency of the sound seems to be visible, so the more digits a number has, the louder it is. I detect long sequences of digits to determine this, but one digit that doesnt fit the pattern and the cycle resets. Would be better to dermine based on the difference between the previous digits.

```
import wave, struct, logging

# open up a wave
w = wave.open('wavefile.WAV', 'rb')
length = w.getnframes()
rate = w.getframerate()
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
count = 0
start = 1
end = 0
startData = 0
endData = 0
for i in range(0,length):
    waveData = w.readframes(1)
    data = struct.unpack("<h", waveData)
    if (start == 1):
        if (len(str(int(data[0])))>=len(str(1234))):
            count=count+1
        else:
            count=0
        if (count == 100):
            startData=i-100
            print("Start "+str(startData/float(rate)))
            count = 0
            start = 0
            end = 1
    if (end == 1):
        if (len(str(int(data[0])))<=len(str(12))):
            count=count+1
        else:
            count=0
        if (count == 10):
            endData=i-10
            print("End "+str(endData/float(rate)))
            count = 0
            start = 1
            end = 0
            frames=endData-startData
            duration=frames/float(rate)
            print("Duration: "+str(duration))
```

Comment: I've try your script but got `struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 2` in unpack line.